# Zooming with VLCJ

Tags: javafx, zooming, vlc, vlcj

Is there any way to zoom in a video with VLCJ like VLC has this feature. I think it is called magnify or interactive zoom.
It is under Tools >> Effects and filters >> Video >> Geometry >> Magnify

I use vlcj with javafx 9, rendering frames to a canvas with an `EmbeddedMediaPlayer`.
I also try to add this magnify filter to `MediaPlayerFactory` like new `MediaPlayerFactory("--video-filter=magnify")` but i have no idea, how to navigate this feature or set zoom level since `"-zoom 2.0"` is not working.

I tried cropping, but that havent worked for me, or i tried really badly.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bare minimum this should work for zooming:

```
mediaPlayer.video().setScale(float factor);
```

Where factor is like 2.0 for double, 0.5 for half and so on.

In my experience, it can be a bit glitchy, and you probably do need to use it in conjunction with crop - and by the way, cropping does work.

But if you want an interactive zoom, then you build that yourself invoking setCrop and setScale depending on some UI interactions you control.

For the picture-in-picture type of zoom, if you're using VLC itself you do something like this:

```
vlc --video-filter=magnify --avcodec-hw=none your-filename.mp4
```

It shows a small overlay where you can drag a rectangle and change the zoom setting.

In theory, that would have been possible to use in your vlcj application by passing arguments to the MediaPlayerFactory:

```
List<String> vlcArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
vlcArgs.add("--avcodec-hw=none");
vlcArgs.add("--video-filter=magnify");

MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
```

The problem is that it seems like you need "--avcodec-hw=none" (to disable hardware decoding) for the magnify filter to work - BUT that option is not supported (and does not work) in a LibVLC application.

So unfortunately you can't get that native "magnify" working with a vlcj application.

A final point - you *can* actually enable the magnify filter if you use LibVLC's callback rendering API (in vlcj this is the CallbackMediaPlayer) as this does not use hardware decoding. However, what you would see is the video with the magnify overlays painted on top but they are not interactive and your clicks will have no effect.

So in short, there's no satisfactory solution for this really.

In theory you could build something yourself, but I suspect it would not be easy.

Comment: Thank you the fast answer, i will try this as soon as i can. I would like to congrat, its a very nice lib, outstanding work.
Do you see any solution to have the picture in picture like the interactive zoom?